# How to prevent button from expanding in QFormLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, size, policy, qformlayout

I have created a subclass of QDialog in PyQt5 and then set a QFormLayout as its layout.
Each row of the layout is defined similar to the following (simplified):
layout.addRow(QLineEdit(), QPushButton('Push Me'))

I have set the dialog to fixed height, but if I stretch the dialog horizontally, the button gets wider and the line edit stays the same width.  What I want is for the line edit to get wider and the button size to remain unchanged.  I have tried setting size policy for the button, but apparently QFormLayout ignores this.  I have also tried making each row of the form layout a QHBoxLayout which contains the line edit and button; this did not work either.  Does anyone have a solution to this problem?  I really need for the button to remain on the right had side of the form.

Comment: Have you checked the [`fieldGrowthPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#fieldGrowthPolicy-prop) property?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.